# Help give a counterexample that countable sum and integration cannot be exchanged in general.

Tags: real-analysis

Given a sequence of functions $f_k$, I understand that $\mathop \smallint \limits_E \mathop \sum \limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {f_k}d\mu  = \mathop \sum \limits_{k = 1}^\infty  \mathop \smallint \limits_E {f_k}d\mu $ are bounded below be some integrable function by monotone convergence theorem. For example, a non-negative function sequence, i.e. $f_k\ge0$, satisfies $\mathop \smallint \limits_E \mathop \sum \limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {f_k}d\mu  = \mathop \sum \limits_{k = 1}^\infty  \mathop \smallint \limits_E {f_k}d\mu $ because $0$ is integrable on any set $E$.

Can anyone help provide a concrete counter example that some $f_k$ does not satisfy this exchangeability? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not clear if you are requiring the functions $f_k$ to satisfy non-negativity, so that the sequence of partial sums satisfies the Monotone Convergence hypothesis, or if you meant to weaken this by assuming merely that $\sum f_k$ is bounded below by some integrable function.

Answer (score 2):

Really there is nothing special about the case of a sum. You can take a sequence like $g_n(x)=n1_{[0,1/n]}(x)$, then $g_n \to 0$ pointwise a.e. but the integrals are all equal to $1$. (This is one of the basic examples where you have pointwise convergence but not convergence of the integral, and it arises because this sequence $g_n$ is not uniformly integrable.)

You can then recast this into a sum by noticing that $g_n=\sum_{k=1}^n g_k - g_{k-1}$, where we introduce $g_0=0$. By taking $f_k=g_k - g_{k-1}$, you get your counterexample.